# Vagrant syncing process

Tags: vagrant

I've just started using Vagrant and I've managed to set up a box ok it seems. I have been a little confused about syncing folders work though. I took from Vagrant that syncing allowed you to use the file system on your Mac and then sync those changes into your virtual machine, is that right?

I have these settings currently

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../../../Library/WebServer/Documents/", "/Users/jonnny/ubuntu-vagrant/www"
```

I would expect that now that when I look in chrome that inside my 127.0.0.1:1234/www/

That the files within my `Library/WebServer/Documents/` would be there. But they're not, have I done it wrong or misunderstood what's going on here?

**Update**

I wasn't sure what you meant with my file/folder structure, so probably best I just show them.

- Users

  - Jonnny

    - ubuntu-vagrant

      ```
      - Vagrantfile
      - /www (dir)
      - bootstrap.sh
      ```
    - VagrantFile
    - VirtualBox VMs

      ```
       - ubuntu-vagrant_342374982374923
                 - box-disk1.vmdk
                 - logs (dir)
                 - ubuntu-vagrant_342374982374923.vbox
      ```

I did try your suggestion and reload the box, but the folder still didn't seem synced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax seems to be correct. But for the second argument, `/Users/jonnny/ubuntu-vagrant/www`, it should be the targeted location **inside the ubuntu filesystem**, not the one which will be created on your Mac OS filesystem.

Try something like `/www/` or `/usr/johnny/www`, according to the location you want.

**Update**

For the vagrant arguments:

- the first should be the location of the folder you want to share inside your Mac Os filesystem relatively from where the `Vagrantfile` is in your Mac Os filesystem.
- the second is where inside the `ubuntu-vagrant` filesystem you want to access these files.

I think your folder structure is not good: you dont need a Vagrantfile folder or a `www` folder in your Mac OS filesystem. Just consider one folder: the one where the `Vagrantfile` is, `Users/Johhny/ubuntu-vagrant`. The `www` folder will just exists inside the VM. Then if the `Library` folder is at the same level than the `Users` folder in your Mac OS filesystem, you should have :

- Library

  - ...
- Users

  - Johhny

    - ubuntu-vagrant

      - `Vagrantfile`
      - `bootstrap.sh`

And inside the `Vagrantfile` you should have this line :

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../../../Library/WebServer/Documents/", "/www", create: true
```

According to the [doc](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html), for the `create: true` paramater : *If true, the host path will be created if it does not exist. Defaults to false.*

Comment: Thanks for your help, I updated my question as I still couldn't get it working, I posted the folder structure to help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I actually understand whats going on. I have figured out my settings now.